# Запуск сценария powershell из проводника с параметрами

Tags: powershell

Есть маленький скрипт powershell отправляющий на печать PDF документ:

```
$pdf = $args[0] #Передаваемый параметр
$printername= "book_print_Kyocera ECOSYS M2135dn KX"
$app='F:\Programm\Full\PDF\2\PDFtoPrinter.exe'
$workingDir = '{0}' -f 'F:\Programm\Full\PDF\2\'
$arglist= '"{0}" "{1}"' -f $pdf, $printername
Start-Process $app -WorkingDirectory $workingDir -ArgumentList $arglist
```

Сценарий на вход принимает 1 параметр - путь к файлу который печатаем.
При запуске сценария из консоли powershell - всё работает замечательно.
(Отправляю команду вида C:\ps\code.ps1 "f:\1\749_.pdf").

При попытке вызова сценария из стороннего приложения (такой же командой C:\ps\code.ps1 "f:\1\749_.pdf") - сценарий запускается, но параметр похоже не передаётся (выходит ошибка что не задан файл который надо печатать).

Пробовал для тестирования создать ярлык сценария и в поле "Объект" указать C:\ps\code.ps1 "f:\1\749_.pdf" - результат аналогичен, параметр не передается.

Господа, подскажите куда "копать"?

P.S. В проводнике установил powershell приложением для открытия файлов ".ps1" по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0):

Запускать PowerShell-скрипт из стороннего приложения нужно так:

```
powershell.exe -File "<путь к скрипту>" <аргументы>
```